# Flask: How to restart Azure App programmatically

Tags: python, azure, api, rest, flask

I have 4 Scrapy spiders that I launch through Flask on Azure. How to restart the application at the click of a button on my website? How to use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/restart#code-try-0) in Flask function?

restart:

```html
<a href="/restart" class="btn btn-danger">Restart</a>
```

flask:

```
@app.route('/restart')
def restart():
    # REST API
```

Comment: why not use python sdk? it's easier than api.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.v2019_08_01.operations.webappsoperations?view=azure-python#restart-resource-group-name--name--soft-restart-none--synchronous-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-)? Where can I find sample code?

Comment: I posted an answer about it. Please let me know if you still have other issues. And please help accept it as answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restart an azure web app, please follow the steps below:

1.Install the following python packages:

[azure-mgmt-resource](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-resource/) and [azure-mgmt-web](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-web/).

2.Then create a service principal for authentication. You can use [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#password-based-authentication) or [azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) to create it. Here is an example by using azure cli:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name xxxx
```

In the output, you can get these items, and write them down:

```
application id(client id)

directory id(tenant)

client secret(secret)
```

Then use the code below:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.web import WebSiteManagementClient

subscription_id ="xxxx" #you can get it from azure portal
client_id ="xxx"
secret="xxx"
tenant="xxx"

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id= client_id,
    secret=secret,
    tenant = tenant
)

#resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)
web_client = WebSiteManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)

#restart your azure web app
web_client.web_apps.restart("your_resourceGroup_name","your_web_app_name")
```